# Issue on jQuery to Customize a Phone Filed Input Box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to customize a a text input box to accept phone in North america format like

```
 (555)-555-5555
```

I tried to use this at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2y4egnym/)

```
var field = $('#phone');
var fieldval = $('#phone').val();
    var length,
    var pattern = [3,6]
    var maxlength = 11;

field.onkeydown = function(event) {
    // Length without hyphen
    length = fieldval.replace("-", "").length;

    if(pattern.indexOf(length) != -1) {
        fieldval = field.value + '-';
    }
    if(fieldval.length > maxlength) {
        fieldval = fieldval.substring(0, maxlength);
    }
}
```

but it is not working! Technically what I need to do is loading adding `()` and `-` whan they meet the specified pathern?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you try this one.

```
$(window).load(function()
{
   var phones = [{ "mask": "(###) ###-####"}, { "mask": "(###) ###-##############"}];
    $('#textbox').inputmask({ 
        mask: phones, 
        greedy: false, 
        definitions: { '#': { validator: "[0-9]", cardinality: 1}} });
});
```

here is the fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/ePDq7/